# Convert CDT Time to my Local Time

Tags: java, date, datetime, unix, epoch

I have been facing trouble understanding the concept of UnixTimestamp being independent of Timezone. So, my server stores all the timestamps in CDT timezone as unixTimestamp (as I have been told). I have to display these timestamps in my Android Application as per my local TimeStamp in milliseconds. I was told, that if I convert the CDT Timestamp to Unix and then display it according to my Local Timezone, it will work. So, I wrote a function as follows, which returns me a unix Timestamp:

```
public static long convertToUnixTSInMillisec(String yyyymmddFormat, String timeZone) { //GMT-5 is Timezone for CDT
    long unixTS = 0;
    DateFormat dfm = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm");

    dfm.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone));//Specify your timezone
    try {
        unixTS = dfm.parse(yyyymmddFormat).getTime();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return unixTS;
}
```

But when I call the above function with different Timezones, it returns different Unix Timestamps, which is not what I expected. I was expecting the same timestamps and the Java function to take care of it.

```
System.out.println(convertToUnixTSInMillisec("201511231500",  TimeZone.getDefault().getID()));
System.out.println(convertToUnixTSInMillisec("201511231500", "GMT-5"));
System.out.println(convertToUnixTSInMillisec("201511231500", "GMT"));
```

Why is this happening? If I want to convert my time as CDT-->Unix-->Local, should I first convert to GMT and then to Unix? CDT-->GMT-->Unix-->Local. Or will the Java Function take care of it as per the Timezone that is passed.

Also, can someone point out code to this right way? I have a time in CDT in yyyyMMddHHmm format, and I want to get unix Timestamp for this?

Comment: Why are you mixing usages of the old time API and the new one? Go all the way and use the new one

Comment: What do you mean by oldTime API and New One?

Comment: You use `TimeZone` which appeared with JSR 310; you use `Date` where, for instance, `LocalDateTime` is available, and `DateFormatter` where `DateTimeFormatter` is available.

Answer (score 1):

What your program is showing is the Unix timestamp for 3pm.  But what 3pm means varies according on the timezone.  You have given three different timezones and so you will get three different timestamps.  3pm in GMT is the same time as 10am in New York and so

```
"201511231000", "GMT-5" and
"201511231500", "GMT"
```

will indeed give the same timestamp.